# Conditional statements in Julia

Tags: julia

I define two non-empty vectors:

```
tmp = [1, 2, 3]
tmp2 = [1, 2]
```

When I type

```
size(tmp, 1) > 0
```

The output is `true`. But when I write

```
size(tmp, 1) > 0 & size(tmp2, 1) > 0
```

it returns false.
When I put each term into a parentheses, as in

```
(size(tmp, 1) > 0) & (size(tmp2, 1) > 0 )
```

it returns true as expected. But I don't understand why `size(tmp, 1) > 0 & size(tmp2, 1) > 0` returns false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a result of 2 things. The first is operator precedence. The code you wrote is parsed as `size(tmp, 1) > (0 & size(tmp2, 1)) > 0` (ie as a chained comparison).

The bigger issue, however is that you probably wanted to use `&&` instead of `&`. `&` is a bitwise and, while `&&` is a logical and. As such, `&&` has the precedence you expect here.